# Empty error message when saving article

Tags: articles

Complete error message when I click save:

```
Error
Save failed with the following error:
```

Using Joomla 3.6.5, admin backend.

Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Can you add a little more info?  Front end edit or backend?  Is error reporting in global config set to maximum?

Answer (score 2):

On the `Server` tab of global configuration set `Error reporting` to `Development` and enable `Debug System` in `System` tab. That should give you a more descriptive error message as well as a back trace.

Comment: I set error reporting to dev, but got same error. Not willing to try "Debug system", since the site is live.

Comment: Change the Access setting for System - Debug plugin to Special. That way only Authors, Super Users and Managers will see the debug info. Then enable it.

Comment: Thank you. The debug console found 9 duplicates, but that can hardly be the reason, can it?

Comment: Also, I think those duplicates are from after the redirect (since Joomla always redirects after saving).

Comment: Easiest solution might be to just copy the article into a new one. Saving the other articles work.

Comment: Duplicates till they don't have the same alias in a same category or same ID they should not create any errors. There has to be something else going on. Did you used any third party plugins?

Comment: Yeah, we use a lot of plugins and components, including our own stuff. It's possible to save the article as a copy.